# How to identify .config or menuconfig entry for a given kernel source code file

Tags: linux, undefined-symbol, kbuild

During compilation of an out of tree driver for a PCIe device (avc8000nano) under Linux Yocto (fsl-community-image, imx6qsabresd, core-image-kernel-dev) I get the following warning messages, which later prohibit to load the driver:

```
WARNING: "videobuf_dma_init_kernel" [/home/root/avc8000nano-112/driver/avc8000.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "videobuf_dma_init" [/home/root/avc8000nano-112/driver/avc8000.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "videobuf_dma_unmap" [/home/root/avc8000nano-112/driver/avc8000.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "videobuf_queue_sg_init" [/home/root/avc8000nano-112/driver/avc8000.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "videobuf_dma_free" [/home/root/avc8000nano-112/driver/avc8000.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "videobuf_dma_map" [/home/root/avc8000nano-112/driver/avc8000.ko] undefined!
```

I think, I've to change the kernel configuration, but I don't know how to get the corresponding .config or menuconfig entry for the source code file, where those symbols are defined.

Comment: I'm trying to get my hands on an `avc8000nano` myself. Any ideas where retail versions can be obtained? They only sell them in large bulks.

Comment: you need to compile AMP's driver for the card. Their website only offers version 1.26, which only support up to kernel 4.17.x. There are newer versions available, however these are only provided to clients